# Convert 3 Dimensional Numpy Array to 4 Dimensional Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to make a simple Program which outputs a video as an Webcam, but the Cam wants a RGBA Numpy Array but I only have RGB from the video. How can I convert the 3 dimensional array to 4 dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually not converting a 3-dimensional array to a 4-dimensional array.  You're changing the size of one of the dimensions from three to four.

Lets say you have a NxMx3 image.  You then need to:

```
temp = np.zeros((N, M, 4))
temp[:,:,0:3] = image
temp[:,:,3] = whatever default alpha you choose to use.
```

Generalize as you see fit.

Comment: I tried it but it gives me this error: `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1080,1920,3) into shape (1080,1920,2)`

Comment: Oops.  Sorry.  Typo.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your existing array is shaped `(xsize, ysize, 3)` and you want to create alpha as a 4th entry all filled with `1`, you should be able to do something like

```
alpha = np.ones((*rgb.shape[0:2], 1))
rgba = np.concatenate((rgb, alpha), axis=2)
```

If you wanted a different uniform alpha value you could use `np.full` with that value instead of `np.ones`, but normally when converting RGB to RGBA you want fully opaque.

Answer (score 0):

You can `np.dstack` your original `im` with `np.ones(im.shape[:2])`

```
new_im = np.dstack((im, np.ones(im.shape[:2])))
```

update: this is equivalent to @hobbs solution `np.concatenate(..., axis=2)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like these: (import numpy as np)

```py
    arr  # shape (n_bands, y_pixels, x_pixels)
    swapped = np.moveaxis(arr, 0, 2)  # shape (y_pixels, x_pixels, n_bands)
    arr4d = np.expand_dims(swapped, 0)  # shape (1, y_pixels, x_pixels, n_bands)
```